# nvlink error when linking CUDA code against CUDA static library - CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, nvcc

I create a static library, which contains some CUDA code and some regular C++ code.
The CMakeLists.txt for this static library looks like this:

```
SET(TARGET_H some_header.h)
SET(CUDA_SRC cudaclass1.cu cudaclass2.cu)
SET(TARGET_SRC cppclass1.cpp cppclass2.cpp)
SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "")
SET(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(somestatic ${TARGET_H} ${TARGET_SRC} ${CUDA_SRC} OPTIONS -arch sm_20)
```

This will produce `libsomestatic.a`.

Now I want to link this static library against an executable, which itself consists of both CUDA code and C++ code.

In the CUDA code of this executable, I need to instantiate and use `CudaClass1` from `libsomestatic.a`.

This is the `CMakeLists.txt` file for the executable:

```
SET(TARGET_H some_header.h)
SET(CUDA_SRC cudafile.cu)
SET(TARGET_SRC main.cpp)
SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "")
SET(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(some_exe ${TARGET_H} ${TARGET_SRC} ${CUDA_SRC} OPTIONS -arch sm_20)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(some_exe somestatic)
```

But I get the following error when building:

```
nvlink error: Undefined reference to '_ZN10test7CudaClass1C1EPKNS_11intE' in ...
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible at all to accomplish this? Linking CUDA code against a library which contains CUDA code?
2. If yes, how would I do this using CMake?

The CUDA documentation states (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#examples)

"It is possible to do multiple device links within a single host executable, as long as each device link is independent of the other (they cannot share code across device executables)"

This sounds like I cannot do what I want to do, right?

I use CUDA 5.5 and GCC 4.8.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: This could be worth forwarding to the NVIDIA developer in charge of `FindCUDA.cmake`.

Comment: I [reported this](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15157) on the bugtracker. Wait & see.

Comment: In the meantime, I ended up making a custom macro that generates the proper compiler/linker commands.

Comment: Could you please post it here?

Comment: Sure, but be warned that it's in a very raw state and could greatly be improved (but I don't have the time for that): https://github.com/bchretien/cmake-cuda-static. Note that the CMake issue was just assigned to a NVIDIA developer, so we may have a clean solution soon.

Comment: Do you suppose you could post / post a link to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to play around with?

Comment: @einpoklum please have a look at the code BenC linked to: https://github.com/bchretien/cmake-cuda-static

Comment: I know this is an old question, but is it not basically the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683575/681865? -- confirmed as an insoluble bug in design of the first generation CUDA support in CMake

Comment: OP, are you still experiencing this issue with recent versions of CMake, and specifically with CMake's recent native support for CUDA?